# ListView.setEmptyView(View) without using XML

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to use the `setEmptyView(View)` method of the `AdapterView` class. I've seen plenty of solutions where you set the empty view as another item in the xml layout and set `android:visibility="gone"`.

But what if I'm not using xml to create my `ListView`? I'm using a `ViewPager` that has each page as a`ListView`. I'm creating the `ListView` objects in java by calling `ListView list = new ListView(Context)`. Then I add each one to the appropriate page in the `instantiateItem(View, position)` method of the pager adapter.

Do I have to somehow add the empty view (I'd want to use a `ProgressBar` ideally) as a child to each `ViewPager` page or should I just add a `LinearLayout` as the root, using xml, instead of having my `ListView` be the root of each page?

Answer (score 2):

The View that you set as [ListView.setEmptyView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) must have the same parent as the ListView. You can create a LinerLayout programmatically and add them both.

Comment: use FrameLayout instead of LineaeLayout, its a light version

Comment: What if I just add the `View` into the `ViewPager` without worrying about creating a `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`? The parent would then be the `ViewPager`.